# Android parsing nested jsonArray

Tags: android, json

I am working with android .I want to parse a nested json array without name.How can I parse these array and store these into a list and the i need to make list of these list.How can I parse these arrays.Thanks in advance.

```
[
    [
        [
            72.837,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.817,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8095,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8082,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.808,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8076,
            18.9562,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8072,
            18.9564,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8071,
            18.9578,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.807,
            18.9617,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.807,
            18.9757,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8072,
            18.9767,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8072,
            18.9768,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8074,
            18.9774,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8088,
            18.9777,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8112,
            18.978,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8414,
            18.9779,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8438,
            18.9778,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8439,
            18.9773,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8439,
            18.9606,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8439,
            18.9583,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8428,
            18.9566,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8423,
            18.9562,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8403,
            18.9561,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.8376,
            18.956,
            0
        ],
        [
            72.837,
            18.956,
            0
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Did you already load that in a JSONArray in your code? Or do you need that part as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); //Where response is your json string
```

Then you can iterate throws this arrays using a for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
    //Do something using :
    //array.get(i) or
    //array.getJsonArray(i) or
    //array.getDouble(i) or
    //...
}
```

Here is the doc for [JsonArray](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

**EDIT** If you want to convert your nested jsonArray into nested java list you can do (not tested)

```
List<List<Double>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response).getJSONArray(0);

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JsonArray nestedArray = jsonArray.get(i);
    List<Double> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0; j< nestedArray.length(); j++) {
        nestedList.add(nestedArray.getDouble(j));
    }
    arrayList.add(nestedList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Gson` with a class like this to parse your `array of arrays of arrays`:

```
public class Example extends ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> {}
```

Comment: For some reason you think I would just post an answer without testing.

Comment: Many people post many things without testing. Unless indicated otherwise, I normally assume it was not tested. Anyway I was just curious

Comment: You should check this one, It has the same principle. I already had to parse a JSON Array with this format at work, so I already tested it irl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736122/using-gson-to-parse-json-array-and-object-with-no-name

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that :-)